# Warning: Multiple step transformation matches to the input

Tags: specflow

I am getting the error in the Step "Warning:Multiple Step transformation matches to the input"..Is there anyway I can turn it off?

My code is

```
public class Transforms
{

    [StepArgumentTransformation(@"\<([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\>$?")]
    public Object ApplyStringTransformations(string TestDataIdentifier)
    {
        GetData Test = new GetData();
        var TestData = Test.ConvertData(TestDataIdentifier);
        return TestData;
    }
}
```

And in the Steps File

```
 [Then(@"I Login as a Member with ""(.*)"" and ""(.*)""")]
    public void ThenILoginAsAMemberWithAnd(object p0,object p1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p0);

    }
```

Comment: Is this the only StepArgumentTransformation you have?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. @GasparNagy this is the only step transformation I have.

Comment: @diegosasw which SpecFlow version you use?

Comment: @GasparNagy `specflow.xunit.3.9.74`

Comment: @diegosasw I see no problem with this transformation, but generally it is not recommended to convert to "object", because that needs to be verified for every single parameter. The warning seems to be invalid though. If you can make a simple repro, please post it to https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues.